# passing sensor_msgs::Image across different processes

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, cv-bridge, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I have a working ROS program that contains two nodes:

1. **usb_cam_node** (`/opt/ros/electric/stacks/bosch_drivers/usb_cam/src/usb_cam_node`) , and
2. A node named **B** that processes videos with cv_bridge.

The basic logic of this program is simple:

1. usb_cam_node gets a video frame from the USB camera, and then publishes a message (of type `sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg`) onto a topic to which B subscribes;
2. B has a callback function that processes the frame upon receiving a message. This callback function looks like this:

**`callbackB(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg){//Do image processing}`**

So far usb_cam_node and B are working fine on Ubuntu 10.10.

Now I plan to move the image processing part within  `callbackB(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)` to a real-time task spawned by [Xenomai](http://www.xenomai.org) APIs within B. B and this real-time task, say, R, are two different processes, although R is spawned within B. In this new version, `callbackB(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)` now only notifies R the receiving of **`msg`** and sends **`&msg`** to R. Once R have **`&msg`**, it is supposed to do the exactly same thing as the old version of callBackB() does. In my experiment, R can read some basic frame (image) info such as **`msg->height`**, which means R should get the correct (?) reference to the image via **`msg`**; However, the whole program crashes when **`cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, enc::BGR8);`** is called.

I am confused here: It seems R gets the correct reference to **`msg`** (i.e., **`&msg`**), as **`msg->height`** gets the correct value. Then why the whole program crashes when  **`cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, enc::BGR8);`** is called? In GDB, I did notice something related to segment fault when this call is executed. Is this related to the fact that **`msg`** is a "smart pointer" instead of a normal C++ pointer? Did I wrongly assume that B and R have the same address space? (But then why R can read **`msg->height`** correctly?)

With Man Thanks,

Tom

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11646/passing-sensor_msgs::image-across-different-processes/) by [TomZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/1266/tomz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-10-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-10**:
`RT_TASKS` spawned by `rt_task_create(..)` or similar can be considered threads, all within the same process. This would make `R` not a "different process" (Just realized this is an old question). Also: `cv_bridge::toCvCopy()` in a real-time task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a couple of different things going on here.

First, the function signature of your node B is indeed a smart pointer; note, however, that ROS messages have *value* semantics, meaning that the image is copied (over the network); this means that your node B has a copy of the image in its address space.

By specifying B's callback to take an `ImageConstPtr`, you've specified that the ROS machinery should (a) get the message over the wire (b) save it as a smart pointer, and (c) pass a copy of that smart pointer to your callback. (Recall that smart pointers do reference counting.)

I can't speak to how Xenomai works; in general, a "process" is something with its own address space, not something that shares addresses; Xenomai may use that term a bit differently, or get around it using memory-mapped files or some other trick. I'll assume that B and R do, in fact, share an address space.

Are you, in fact, passing `&msg` to R? If so, that's likely your problem. Taking `&msg` generates a raw pointer to a smart pointer; then, when B's callback finishes, it destroys `msg`, and the ROS worker threads destroy their copy (because the callback is done), and now `&msg` points to a destroyed value, and you risk a segfault.

The easy fix is to have your callback take an `ImagePtr`, not an `ImageConstPtr`, and then to pass the smart pointer to R, not a raw pointer; that way, everybody gets a reference, and when B's callback and ROS' copies are destroyed, R still has a valid reference, with count 1.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1